# Laravel select posts and comments for active users only

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three models namely `Users, Posts and Comments`.

Users table

```
id  username active
1   guyd        1
2   mohok       0
3   cotra       0
```

Posts table

```
id  post_content user_id
1   Hello         1
2   World         2
3   Foo           3
```

Comments table

```
id post_id   user_id   commment_body
1       1       2       Great post
2       1       3       Totally disagree
3       2       1       Nice read
4       2       3       Wow
5       1       1       Thanks guys
```

My Posts Model has

```
public function latestComments($limit = 3)
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)
      ->where('voided', '=', 0)
      ->with('user')
      ->join('users as comment_owner', 'comments.user_id', '=', 'comment_owner.id')
      ->where('comment_owner.active', '=', 1)
      ->orderByDesc('comments.updated_at')
      ->limit($limit);
  }
```

My Comments model has

```
public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
```

I want to fetch only posts and comments from users whose active=1. I am using the following but it's giving the wrong results. It's assigning comments to posts without comments.

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('posts.created_at', 'DESC')
      ->with('user')
      ->with('latestComments')
      ->join('users as post_owner', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'post_owner.id')
      ->where('active', 1)
      ->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `whereHas()`

```
Post::latest()
    ->with('user', 'latestComments')
    ->whereHas('user', function ($q) {
        $q->where('active', 1);
    })
    ->paginate(5);
```

If you also want to filter comments:

```
->with(['user', 'latestComments' => function ($q) {
    $q->whereHas('user', function ($q) {
        $q->where('active', 1);
    });
}])
```